# Access files from another subdirectory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with a few nested folders, and I have trouble accessing some of the folders from my current working directory.I am currently working on this in Python 3.6

Here is the current file directory structure:

```
../PROJECT
../PROJECT/REVIEWS/RESULTS/excel_file.xlsx
../PROJECT/LDA_MODEL/TOPIC_MODEL/model.py
```

If my current working directory is `../PROJECT/LDA_MODEL/TOPIC_MODEL`, how can I access the `/PROJECT/REVIEWS/RESULTS/excel_file.xlsx` without changing my current working directory?

Comment: Have you tried using `..` to refer to the parent directory? E.g. the path `Dir/Child/../` refers to the directory `Dir`

Comment: You can just do
`filepath = "../PROJECT/REVIEWS/RESULTS/excel_file.xlsx"`

Note: Filepath should be from the root.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do so using os.path

If your current working directory is `../PROJECT/LDA_MODEL/TOPIC_MODEL/`, then you can try this:

```
import os
my_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("..", "..", "REVIEWS", "RESULTS", "excel_file.xlsx"))
```

- `os.path.abspath` will return to you the absolute pas to the path you're looking for.
- `os.path.join` will create a path respecting your OS' path structure ("\" on Windows vs "/" on Linux for example). It's usually safer than typing yourself. In this case, on Windows, the os.path.join will return `"..\\..\\REVIEWS\\RESULTS\\excel_file.xlsx"`.
- `".."` means you go one directory UP.

If you need to access a file using an absolute path, start your os.path.join with `"/"`

```
import os
my_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join("/", "MY", "PATH", "TO", "MY", "FILE"))
```

Again, it will depend on your OS, but on Windows this will return: `"C:\\MY\\PATH\\TO\\MY\\FILE\\"`